# Sitecore Error says 'The service isn't online.' in the logs

Tags: web-services, integration, sitecore, sitecore6, telligent

After I install the Telligent Connect package in the Sitecore installation of JetStream demo site it started getting runtime error when opening the JetStream site or Sitecore Admin. From the Sitecore logs using Sitecore Log Analyser it shows below error message frequently in the logs.

PS: Logs location I refer is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JSTDemo\Data\logs`

I have Sitecore 6.6 and Telligent 7.0 version setups. Also while installing the Telligent Connect the package it asked to replace the Ninject.dll I had refused to replace the file (if that affects something).

I have setup the Telligent Community Site and JetStream in same local environment and both were working fine individually but after installing Telligent Connect it has collapsed the Sitecore Jetstream site.

I have been trying to integrate the both since two days with many Fresh (cleaned up) attempts but no success after the Telligent Connect package installation.

I am newbie in Sitecore world. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

> 5588 13:46:00 03.05.2013 ERROR The service isn't online. Exception:
>   System.Net.WebException Message: The request failed with HTTP status
>   417: Expectation failed. Source: System.Web.Services at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall) at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at
>   CRMSecurityProvider.crm4.discoveryservice.CrmDiscoveryService.Execute(Request
>   Request) at
>   CRMSecurityProvider.Service.CrmTicketManager.GetSPLATicket(AuthenticationType
>   authType, String url, String login, String password, String
>   organizationName) at
>   CRMSecurityProvider.Service.CrmTicketManager.GetTicket(String url,
>   String login, String password, String organizationName,
>   AuthenticationType authType, String partner, String environment) at
>   CRMSecurityProvider.crm4.webservice.CrmService.GetActive(ConfigurationSettings
>   settings)
>
> 5588 13:46:01 03.05.2013 ERROR The service isn't online. Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Source: CRMSecurityProvider at
>   CRMSecurityProvider.crm4.webservice.CrmService.GetActiveMetadata(ConfigurationSettings
>   settings)
>
> 5588 13:46:02 03.05.2013 ERROR The CRM provider couldn't be
>   initialized: The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation
>   failed.

There is one more error occuring

> ManagedPoolThread #1 13:38:44 03.05.2013 ERROR Error committing data
>   row Visits.4c1cda28-1d8b-4365-aebb-30e1bed1d1ec : The UPDATE statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Visits_Locations". The
>   conflict occurred in database "JSTDemoJetstream_Analytics", table
>   "dbo.Locations", column 'LocationId'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

And a Warning message

> ManagedPoolThread #1 13:38:44 03.05.2013 WARN Errors while
>   committing data. Retrying... System.Exception: Error committing
>   datatable: Visits ---> System.Exception: Commit error: The UPDATE
>   statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Visits_Locations". The conflict occurred in database
>   "JSTDemoJetstream_Analytics", table "dbo.Locations", column
>   'LocationId'. The statement has been terminated.
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters.Sql.SqlDataAdapterProvider.Update(DataTable
>   table, UpdateOptions options) at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters.Sql.SqlDataAdapterProvider.Update(DataTable
>   table) at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters.Sql.SqlDataAdapterProvider.Update(DataSet
>   dataSet)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters.Sql.SqlDataAdapterProvider.Update(DataSet
>   dataSet) at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters.DataAdapterManager.Update(DataSet
>   dataSet) at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitDataSet.CommitAnalytics.Process(CommitDataSetArgs
>   args) at (Object , Object[] ) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain) at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args) at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackerChanges.Flush()

Also If that affects I have enabled the Telligent Analytics,

```
<add name="JavascriptAnalyticsHttpModule" type="Telligent.Evolution.ExtendedAnalytics.JavascriptAnalyticsHttpModule, Telligent.Evolution.ExtendedAnalytics" />
```

and

```
<add verb="GET" name="analytics" path="analytics.ashx" type="Telligent.Evolution.ExtendedAnalytics.ExtendedAnalyticsRequestHandler, Telligent.Evolution.ExtendedAnalytics" />
<add verb="GET" name="analyticsUrls" path="/utility/analytics/router.aspx" type="Telligent.Evolution.AnalyticsUrls.Http.AnalyticsUrlHttpHandler, Telligent.Evolution.AnalyticsUrls" />
```

### UPDATE

After I disabled the config for Telligent located at `\App_Config\Include\TelligentEvolution.config` the sitecore site is up and running. So it seems the Telligent part is creating issues..

Comment: Have you asked telligent about this? Get in touch with MKelley-Telligent.

Comment: I had asked about this on telligent support, let me recheck with MKelley..